# How to Convert my XML Data using the below line of code in Java?

Tags: java, json, xml, jaxb

Suppose I have  below XML tag data and I am converting it in JSON using Jaxb, I am new to his technology, While Implementing @XMLElementWrapper:Only field inside its @XmlElement will be shown and converted. How to do it correctly

```
 @XmlRootElement(name = "O")
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 public class JSONObjectConversion {

    @XmlElement(name = "Header")
      private List<DTO> header = null;

    public List<DTO> getHeaderMetadata() {
    return header;
     }

     public void setUsers(List<DTO> header) {
     this.header = header;
      }

     @XmlElementWrapper(name="Product")
     @XmlElement(name="Barcode")

      private List<DTO> product = null;

      public List<DTO> getProductMetadata() {

       return product;
       }

    public void setNextUsers(List<DTO> nextusers) {
       this.product = nextusers;

      }
       }`
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Can you post your expected JSON and the actual result?